# CNN prediction using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, prediction

I'm quite new to python and tensorflow, but already managed to build, train and validate a CNN with my own database of images saved as tf.records.
Now I want the model to read in a single picture and predict in real-time. Therefore, I wanted to modify my validation script by getting rid of the parser (which decoded my images saved as tf.records) and didn't batch the input images, since I only want to predict one. Somehow I always get the following Error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, bfloat16, float32, float64
```

I took a closer look at the script I used to create the tf.records and compared them to the parser I used in the scripts for training and validation, but wasn't able to find the mistake.

I would be thankful, if you could help me to find the mistake or show me an easier way to predict the classes with an already trained CNN.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

num_classes = 2
crop_top = 5
crop_bottom = 10
crop_sides = 5
img_size_height = 80
img_size_width = 100
model_dir = "./2cv_128fc"


def load_image():
    img = cv2.imread('./dir_pred_img/img_2.jpg')
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size_width + (2 * crop_sides), img_size_height + crop_top + crop_bottom),
                     interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = img[crop_top:(img_size_height + crop_top), crop_sides:(img_size_width + crop_sides)]
    features = {'image': img}
    return features


def conv_nn(input_layer):
    conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, name='conv_layer_1', filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same',
                              activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv_1, pool_size=2, strides=2)
    conv_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool_1, name='conv_layer_2', filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same',
                              activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv_2, pool_size=2, strides=2)
    flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(pool_2)
    fc_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flatten, name='fully_connected_layer', units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    fc_layer = tf.layers.dropout(fc_layer, rate=0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
    output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc_layer, name='output_layer', units=num_classes)
    return output_layer


def model_fn(features):
    input_layer = features["image"]
    input_layer = tf.identity(input_layer, name="input_tensor")
    input_layer = tf.reshape(input_layer, [-1, img_size_height, img_size_width, 1])  # 1.tensor 2.shape
    input_layer = tf.identity(input_layer, name="input_tensor_reshaped")

    logits = conv_nn(input_layer)

    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
    return pred


model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=model_dir)
prediction = list(model.predict(input_fn=load_image))
print(prediction[0])
```

full error message:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Input graph does not use tf.data.Dataset or contain a QueueRunner. That means predict yields forever. This is probably a mistake.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/create_data/pred_img.py", line 54, in <module>
    prediction = list(model.predict(input_fn=load_image))
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 577, in predict
    features, None, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1195, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/create_data/pred_img.py", line 47, in model_fn
    logits = conv_nn(input_layer)
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/create_data/pred_img.py", line 27, in conv_nn
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\convolutional.py", line 417, in conv2d
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 817, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 374, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 757, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 194, in call
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 868, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 520, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 204, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1043, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 609, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, bfloat16, float32, float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code descirbes how you can implement this with keras.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Cropping2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import cv2
import numpy as np

# parameters
num_classes = 2
crop_top = 5
crop_bottom = 10
crop_sides = 5
img_size_height = 80
img_size_width = 100
channels = 3
input_shape = (img_size_height, img_size_width, channels)
activation = 'relu'
learning_rate = 0.0001

if num_classes == 2:
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
else:
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'


test_image = image.load_img('./data/img.png')
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
input_shape = test_image.shape

def model(input_shape=input_shape):

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

   # cropping=((pixels_from_top, pixels_from_bottom), (pixels_from_left, pixels_from_right))
    cropping = Cropping2D(cropping=((crop_top, crop_bottom), (crop_sides, crop_sides)))(inputs)
    conv_1 = Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=activation)(cropping)
    pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv_1)
    conv_2 = Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=activation)(pool_1)
    pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv_2)

    flatten = Flatten()(pool_2)
    dense_1 = Dense(128, activation=activation, name='fully_connected_layer')(flatten)
    dropout = Dropout(0.5)(dense_1)

    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=loss, metrics=['acc', 'mse', 'mae'])
    model.summary()

    return model

test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
model = model(input_shape)
# note that without training we will only get random results
prediction = model.predict_on_batch(test_image)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.
But since I already trained my CNN and I have to use Tensorflow, Keras is not an option for me.
I will try to understand the Keras Model and hope that this will help me to get the tensorflow model to work. 
the model.predict_on_batch()  command might help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I added following line to the end of def load_image() and returned dataset instead of feautures.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(features)
return dataset
```